# Artifactory webhooks are not getting triggered

Tags: artifactory, webhooks

I am not able to trigger an Artifactory webhook. I have followed the same steps as mentioned here https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/webhook just changed the webhook.config.json file contents. Reloaded the plugins and reloaded the webhook configurations as well.

I have copied the webhook.config.json.sample to webhook.config.json into the artifactory-pro-6.3.3\etc\plugins folder.

Reloaded the plugins: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ReloadPlugins

Also, Loaded the configuration: https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/webhook#making-changes-to-the-configuration

```
{
  "webhooks": {
    "awesomewebhook": {
        "url": "http://localhost:5000",
        "events": [
            "storage.afterCreate",
            "storage.afterDelete",
            "storage.afterMove",
            "storage.afterCopy",
            "storage.afterPropertyCreate",
            "storage.afterPropertyDelete",
            "execute.pingWebhook"
        ]
    }
  },
  "debug": true,
  "timeout": 15000
}
```

Even when I am running hitting http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/plugins/pingWebhook nothing happens I just get an empty JSON response

```
{
}
```

What am I missing over here?

Comment: Have you tried using `http://localhost:5000`?

Answer (score 0):

Port for `localhost` in the config is `5000` but you're hitting `localhost:8081`.